# mod_rewrite RewriteCond falsly doesn't match pattern

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, conditional-statements

This is driving me insane. I have a very simple pattern I wish to match:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .? - [E=tpl:%{REQUEST_URI}]

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} a
RewriteRule .? - [E=tpl:presentation]

RewriteRule .? index.php?tpl=%{ENV:tpl} [QSA,L]
```

Within *index.php* I currently simply `var_dump($_REQUEST);` to check the value of tpl. Whenever I access the URI `/aaa_foo/bar` it dumps that same URI. If, however, I replace the *'a'* in the RewriteCond with a simple *'.'* or negate the condition, it dumps *'presentation'*.

I am completely unable to understand why the *'a'* does not match when clearly there are three to be found in the string. Am I missing something?

Please note: I have resorted to simply using `RewriteRule ^/bar - [E=tpl:presentation]` without the `RewriteCond`, nonetheless I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong up there.

If the URI contains the 'a' character (which it does in my example), that variable tpl is to be assigned the value presentation. Accordingly the output should no longer be the requested URI but presentation

Comment: What you have there doesn't make a lot of sense. They're regular expressions so I don't actually see how everything won't match the first rule. `.` means match *any* character. You'd be better of describing the behaviour you want with examples of the URLs and what you want them rewritten to

Comment: @arco444 Of course everything is supposed to match the first rule. Consider the first rule the default value for the env variable tpl which is set to the requested URI. If the URI contains the 'a' character (which it does in my example), that variable _tpl_ is to be assigned the value _presentation_. Accordingly the output should no longer be the requested URI but _presentation_, just as it is when I use the other other mentioned patterns. Maybe you're forgetting that mod_rewrite does not abort after the first matched rule unless the [L] flag is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the 2nd rule, it should be `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `${REQUEST_URI}`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} a
RewriteRule .? - [E=tpl:presentation]
```

Or better just:

```
RewriteRule a - [E=tpl:presentation]
```

Comment: Good lord, I knew it had to be something extremely trivial. Thanks a lot, I didn't see that! (Regarding your "or better just", I had that idea immediately after I hit the post button.)

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated? The below should do what you want:

```
RewriteRule a index.php?tpl=presentation [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* index.php?tpl=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Comment: See my appended note. Immediately after I submit the question, I had that very idea. Thank you. Nonetheless since anubhava's response points out my mistake, I'll accept his answer.